# How to best create a CancellationTokens from within a .NET Core/5's Controller method

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await

What's the best way to provide a `CancellationToken` to a `Controller`'s endpoint method?

Passing it in as a parameter seems to break `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen`'s `swagger.json` generation albeit being the recommended way for previous versions of dotNET.

Comment: When you say it breaks swagger.json generation... how? You may be able to create a swashbuckle filter to pull the parameter out of the documentation, but still support cancellation.

Comment: @Kit oh, I'm aware of the filters but for my specific case I didn't want to maintain one more filter besides the feature flag and auth ones. Without the filter the swagger.json generation would go on forever and since the base class already exposes such property I thought why not leverage what's already built-in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Swashbuckle doesn't support it, it's a major oversight on their part and you should report it.

But you can use the [`HttpContext.RequestAborted` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.requestaborted).

Comment: They support it as far as you create a filter like @Kit commented on the question, such as on this issue on their repo https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/161 , but using the Context's seems like fair less headache than spinning a filter for every project I'd like to have a cancellable request

Comment: A note here: for .NET 5 and Swashbuckle >= 6.2.1 `CancellationToken`s are automatically filtered and, thus, having them on the endpoint is actually the best path to go!

Answer (score 1):

--- Update

It seems that the latest versions of `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` (>= `6.2.1` from the latest projects I've played with) the `CancellationToken`s that are created within the endpoint's method signature are *automatically filtered*! Thus it's way handier to declare them there than the workaround below!

Code sample for .NET 5 and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`, notice that no filters or attributes are required to rule out the `CancellationToken` as something that is automatically injected for us as a request hits that endpoint.

```cs
    [ApiController]
    [Route(Constants.DefaultRoute)]
    public class WorkoutsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ISender sender;

        public WorkoutsController(ISender sender)
        {
            this.sender = sender ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(sender));
        }

        [HttpGet("{SportId}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<Workout>))]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ListAll([FromRoute] ListWorkouts query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            IEnumerable<Workout> result = await sender.Send(query, cancellationToken);
            if (result is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
```

--- Previous Version of this Answer

So far my working solution is to tap into `ControllerBase.HttpContext.RequestAborted` property and envelop it on an **extension method** such that when it's not available (e.g.: when you're unit testing) it won't fail with a `NullReference`.

The extension method itself:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Methods to extend a ControllerBase.
/// </summary>
public static class ControllerBaseExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtains the CancellationToken from a HTTP Request or a new one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controller"></param>
    /// <returns>A CancellationToken ready to use</returns>
    public static CancellationToken GetCancellationToken(this ControllerBase controller)
    {
        return controller?.HttpContext?.RequestAborted ?? default;
    }
}
```

This allows me to pass in `CancellationToken`s for my Controller's dependencies. The following snippet shows how this method can be used to feed a Token into MediatR's `IMediator`:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateFeed command)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    try
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(command, this.GetCancellationToken()); // Allows you to handle cancellation during IRequest handling
        return Created(string.Empty, result);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        return NoContent();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Erro ao tentar criar um novo Feed: {@Command}", command);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alves.
Mind that the argument should be CancellationToken and not Nullable CancellationToken (CancellationToken? ) as it won't work then. This has driven me crazy for some time before figuring out the issue).

Comment: That makes sense hah - the DI is "lazy" by default for parameters and providing a `null` is easier than an instance of a `CancelationToken`